# Matlab: How to build array with strings at specific index

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a cell array of strings (length = 4):
     `A = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}`
I have a double matrix of indices (length = 4):
     `B = [2, 4, 6, 8]`

How can I create a new cell array `C` (of strings) of `length = 8`, that uses the indices in `B` to place the strings from `A` into the new array `C`. For any index not specified in `B`, I want to enter a `' '` space (empty string).  Note: my real data does not go "every-other".

`C = {' ', 'a', ' ', 'b', ' ', 'c', ' ', 'd'}`

How can this be done in Matlab?

Comment: how did you come with 8? Is it `4+4`, or is it the maximum index in `B`?

Comment: No, the lengths of `A`, `B`, and `C` were arbitrary, except that the lengths of `A` and `B` need to be equal (because the indices in `B` correspond to the strings in `A`).

Comment: what I meant was, what if B was `B=[100 200 300 400]`?

Comment: Yes, the values of `B` could be `[100, 200, 300, 400]`, but then my new cell array `C` would need to be at least length = 400 or greater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
C = repmat({' '}, 1, max(B)); %// predefine with ' ';
C(B) = A; %// replace actual values
```

Or:

```
C(B) = A; %// this automatically fills missing values with [] 
ind = cellfun('isempty', C); %// find occurrences of [] 
C(ind) = repmat({' '}, 1, sum(ind)); %// replace them with ' '
```

The last line could be simplified as follows (no `repmat` needed), as noted by @ParagS.Chandakkar:

```
C(ind) = {' '}; %// replace them with ' '
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I would only add this step before your code, to create the empty cell array `C = repmat({''},1,8);`

Answer (score 2):

This is another approach, very similar to the above, but no `repmat`.

```
C(B)=A;
C(cellfun('isempty',C))={' '};
```

I have replaced traditional `@isempty` since it may be [faster](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/cellfun-undocumented-performance-boost). Thanks @LuisMendo for mentioning that in a comment.

Comment: `C(cellfun('isempty',C))` may be [faster](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/cellfun-undocumented-performance-boost) than `C(cellfun(@isempty,C))`